# Can Tangosol Coherence cache non-serializable objects?

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

I'm using Tangosol Coherence v3.2.2b371. Can I cache objects that do not implement *Serializable* through the *NamedCache* api? Or this depends on configuration?

---

Edit: For clarification, I'm trying to cache compiled *javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression* objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store an object in the cache it must be serializable but does not have to implement Serializable. Specifically, it can use [POF](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/api_pof.htm#COHDG5182) which is more efficient in time and memory than Serializable.

POF does require some additional configuration, which is described in the article I linked to.

Comment: Hi, the tangosol docs you linked state that POF starts with Coherence 3.2, and not 3.4.

Comment: You're right. POF was introduced in 3.2. I fixed my answer. I've only worked with 3.4 and 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (just guessing) that the answer is "no". However, do take a look at the PortableObject interface. This is supposed to be an alternative to java.io.Serializable, but for performance reasons. You should check whether it can be used to replace Serializable interface.

[PortableObject JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/350/com/tangosol/io/pof/PortableObject.html)

Answer (score 1):

Coherence can cache non-Serializable but POF-aware (either PortableObject or one having a registered PofSerializer) objects starting with 3.4.

Before that POF (or any other custom Serializer for that matter) was not usable as a storage (within the backing map) and tranport format within the cluster (on the TCMP protocol), it was only used as a transport protocol in TCP*Extend.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on configuration. If you need to store objects that don't support serialization, you need to have a com.tangosol.io.Serializer implementation that can do the serialization *on behalf of* the non-serializable objects. You may find that for common cases, this is already supported by e.g. a PofSerializer.